# AWS Ec2 image builder cron expression

Tags: amazon-web-services, ec2-ami

I would like to schedule a cron that runs once week on Saturday @ 9pm. Here is the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/imagebuilder/latest/userguide/cron-expressions.html

This is what I tested so far with no luck. Still digging what I am doing wrong. I would appreciate any feedback..

```
"0 21 ? * sat *" # Run at  9PM (UTC) every Saturday
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This crontab entry should work:

```
0 21 * * Sat
```